# Initializing an Array of HashSet<string>, clarification needed

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, hashset

I initialize something like this

```
    public Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>[]> historgram = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>[]>()
    {
        {0, new HashSet<string>[3]},
        {1, new HashSet<string>[3]},
        {2, new HashSet<string>[3]},
    };
```

I then

```
        if (historgram.TryGetValue(daysAgo, out data))
        {
            if (t.isTestAutomated)
            {
                if (data[0] == null)
                    data[0] = new HashSet<string>();

                data[0].Add(t.id);
            }
```

The above works. If I have data to put, I initialize at run time

Once all is done, I write up a Json and end up with nulls for those instances where I didnt have anyting to put in. It looks something like this

```
"historgram": {
  "0": [ null, null, null ],
  "1": [ null, null, null ],
  "2": [ null, null, null ],
  "3": [ null, null, null ],
  "4": [
    [ "XXXX-2244" ],
    null,
    null
  ],
```

**Instead I'd like to end up with empty []. How can I pre-initialize HashSet to be empty straight away?**

Comment: That seems correct. *The array has a length of 3.. and all 3 values are null.* The capacity and length of an array are the same. If using a List<..> eg, I would expect the serialization to honor the (dynamic) length of the collection. Otherwise, perhaps a custom converter? Which would depend on the JSON serialization..

Comment: @user2864740, indeed it is. I was wondering how to display [] (initialized empty) instead of null if possible.

Comment: Initialize the arrays to length 0?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend changing the string[] to a List so you can easily manage the size from 0 to 3 or more.

```
public static Dictionary<int, List<HashSet<string>>> historgram = new Dictionary<int, List<HashSet<string>>>()
{
    {0, new List<HashSet<string>>()},
    {1, new List<HashSet<string>>()},
    {2, new List<HashSet<string>>()},
};
```

You can use the above in your code like this,

```
if (historgram.TryGetValue(2, out List<HashSet<string>> data)) 
if (data == null)
{
    data = new List<HashSet<string>>();
    data.Add(new HashSet<string>() { "XXXX-2244" });
}
else
{
    data.Add(new HashSet<string>() { "XXXX-2255" });
}
```

At this point, your original histogram is also updated. Note that data is a reference to value of your dictionary's key.

```
dynamic output = new ExpandoObject();
output.histogram = historgram;
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output, Formatting.Indented));

// Generates the following output...
{
  "histogram": {
    "0": [],
    "1": [],
    "2": [
      [
        "XXXX-2255"
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```